# Как задать строке задний фон в QTableView, если данные цвета хранятся в БД?

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, table, делегаты

У меня есть в Базе таблица log:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней хранятся условные обозначения цветов в колонки color. Есть вторая таблица data которая связана с log по колонке id_log :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне с помощью делегатов задать цвет заднего фона строк, относительно того к какому журналу относиться запись в data таблице?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Построение таблицы data в программе:

```
void MainWindow::TableLogBuilding() {
    Login connLog;
    connLog.connOpen();
    QSqlError dbError;
    QSqlQuery *queryLog = new QSqlQuery(connLog.mydb);
    QStandardItemModel *modelLog = new QStandardItemModel;
    QStandardItem *itemLog;
    int rowLog = 0;
    bool queryTableRes = queryLog->exec("SELECT * FROM public.data");
    if (queryTableRes) {
        //Заголовки столбцов
        QStringList horizontalHeader;
        horizontalHeader.append("Название файла");
        horizontalHeader.append("Кликабельные ссылки на файл");
        horizontalHeader.append("Широта");
        horizontalHeader.append("Долгота");
        horizontalHeader.append("Журнал");
        modelLog->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontalHeader);
        while (queryLog->next()) {
            itemLog = new QStandardItem(queryLog->value(1).toString());
            modelLog->setItem(rowLog, 0, itemLog);
            itemLog = new QStandardItem(queryLog->value(2).toString());
            modelLog->setItem(rowLog, 1, itemLog);
            itemLog = new QStandardItem(queryLog->value(3).toString());
            modelLog->setItem(rowLog, 2, itemLog);
            itemLog = new QStandardItem(queryLog->value(4).toString());
            modelLog->setItem(rowLog, 3, itemLog);
            itemLog = new QStandardItem(queryLog->value(5).toString()); // id_log журнал к которому относиться запись
            modelLog->setItem(rowLog, 4, itemLog);
            rowLog++;
        }
    }else{
        dbError = connLog.mydb.lastError();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", dbError.text(), QMessageBox::Close);
    }
    HrefDelegate *HrefD = new HrefDelegate(this);
    TableLog->setModel(modelLog);
    TableLog->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, HrefD);
    ColorDelegate *ColorD = new ColorDelegate(this);
    TableLog->setItemDelegate(ColorD);
    connLog.connClose();
}
```

colordelegate.h :

```
#ifndef COLORDELEGATE_H
#define COLORDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QObject>

class ColorDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ColorDelegate(QObject *parent);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // COLORDELEGATE_H
```

colordelegate.cpp

```
#include "colordelegate.h"
#include <QColor>

ColorDelegate::ColorDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {

}

void ColorDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

}

void ColorDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

        const int rows = index.model()->rowCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            QModelIndex idx = model->index(i, 4);

            model->data(idx,Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

        }

}
```

Comment: Надо унаследовать модель и возвращать цвет в `data ()` для `Qt::BackgroundRole`. Как вариант, можно не наследовать, а создать проксю... и не используй `QStandardItemModel` — для sql'я есть готовые `QSqlTableModel` и `QSqlQueryModel`; в данном случае лучше даже подойдёт `QSqlRelationalTableModel`, если модель нужно редактировать...

Comment: А чем плоха QStandardItemModel, в данной ситуации?

Comment: как минимум тем, что её приходится вручную заполнять... и высока вероятность получить из этого целый веер различных проблем...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Можно привести пример, того как лучше изменить код. Пока в таком подходе я вижу плюсы в том, что могу назначить цвет строк, задать заголовки которые мне нужны, а не которые хранятся в базе. Работая с PHP я заполнял в ручную, некоторые таблицы, особенно мультиязычный сайты и не видел в этом подходе проблемы.

Comment: если кратко, то весь код приведённый в вопросе нужно выбросить и начать заново… не обещаю, но, если будет настроение может набросаю примерчик попозже… заголовки можно установить, и в модели `QAbstractItemModel:setHeaderData ()` (и переопределённые варианты), в виде этого делать по возможности, не стоит т.к. например возникнут проблемы при перетаскивание/отключении столбцов… по поводу цвета строк — суть вопроса как раз в том, что это сделать у тебя не получается… Пыха сильно развращает… Проблемы, например, возникнут, когда нужно будет обновить таблицу и не потерять текущую выделенную строчку…

Comment: @Fat-Zer На вопрос я уже сам себе  ответил. На него не обязательно отвечать, а как более корректно сделать код за это я буду вам очень благодарен, если напишите.

Comment: ради  интереса (не чтобы уесть. а ради понимания механики сайта), реакции на ответ нет потомучто он не интересне или просто уведомления об ответе не приходят? или просто ответ затерялся в личном ревью-листе?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Прошу прощения за то что я долго молчал. Ответ интересен . Я уже просто свой вариант накидал. Сейчас проверю ваш.

Comment: Встречно извиняюсь, когда писал предыдущее сообщение, честно говоря был нетрезв и до сих пор сильно комплексую по этому поводу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Example]

Полностью самостоятельный пример цветной proxy-модели и её применения одним файлом:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <assert.h>

#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QTableView>
#include <QtGui/QIdentityProxyModel>

#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRecord>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRelationalDelegate>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRelationalTableModel>

class ColorizeProxyModel: public QIdentityProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColorizeProxyModel (QObject *parent = 0)
        : QIdentityProxyModel (parent), m_colorColumn (0) {}
    virtual ~ColorizeProxyModel () {}

    void setColorColum (int col) { m_colorColumn = col; }
    int colorColumn () { return m_colorColumn; }

    virtual QVariant data (const QModelIndex &id, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
      if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole) {
        QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource (id);
        QModelIndex colorStrIndex = sourceIndex.sibling (sourceIndex.row (), m_colorColumn);
        QString colorName = colorStrIndex.model ()->data (colorStrIndex).toString ();
        return QBrush (QColor (colorName));
      } else {
        return QIdentityProxyModel::data(id, role);
      }
    }

private:
    int m_colorColumn;
};

void queryOrDie (QString qStr, QSqlDatabase db) {
    QSqlQuery q = db.exec (qStr);
    if (q.lastError ().isValid ()) {
        qDebug () << "Query failed: " << qStr;
        qDebug () << "With error:   " << q.lastError ();
        abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase ("QMYSQL");
    db.setDatabaseName ("test");
    bool ok = db.open ();
    assert (ok); assert (db.isOpen());

    queryOrDie ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data", db);
    queryOrDie ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS color", db);

    queryOrDie ("CREATE TABLE color ("
                "  id INT PRIMARY KEY,"
                "  name VARCHAR(64)"
                ")", db);
    queryOrDie ("CREATE TABLE data ("
                 "  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                 "  data VARCHAR(64),"
                 "  color_id INT,"
                 "  FOREIGN KEY (color_id) REFERENCES color(id)"
                 ")", db);

    queryOrDie ("INSERT INTO color (id, name) VALUES"
                "  (0, 'cyan'), (1, 'coral'), (2, '#f12443')", db);
    queryOrDie ("INSERT INTO data (data, color_id) VALUES"
                "  ('hello world', 0), ('goodbye world', 1), ('some mash', 2)", db);

    QSqlRelationalTableModel model (0, db);
    model.setTable ("data");
    int colorCol = model.record ().indexOf ("color_id");
    model.setHeaderData (model.record ().indexOf ("id"),   Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr ("Number"));
    model.setHeaderData (model.record ().indexOf ("data"), Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr ("Data"));
    model.setRelation (colorCol, QSqlRelation ("color", "id", "name"));
    model.setHeaderData (colorCol, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr ("Color"));
    model.setEditStrategy (QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    model.select ();

    ColorizeProxyModel colorModel;
    colorModel.setSourceModel (&model);
    colorModel.setColorColum (colorCol);

    QTableView *tbl = new QTableView ();
    tbl->setModel (&colorModel);
    tbl->setWindowTitle (QObject::tr ("A colorful table"));
    tbl->hideColumn (colorCol);
    tbl->show ();

    model.select ();
    return a.exec ();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Пример подразумевает, что база `test` уже существует и у текущего пользователя есть право на локальное подключение без пароля.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень признателен. Но аврал . Задаю часто вопросы. На те которые уже сам ответил, стараюсь пропускать. Через месяц дедлайн, а на работе все как лебедь, рак и щука