# Покраска строки в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Мне нужно покрасить строку в QTableView. Я использую QSqlQueryModel. Мне нужно покрасить не элемент, а именно строку. Если я правильно понимаю, это делается при помощи QItemDelegate.

Я понимаю, что здесь уже достаточно много решённых вопросов, таких как мой, но всё равно прошу помочь мне.

Comment: Проще, наверное, через роль. Отнаследоваться от QSqlQueryModel и в переопрделенных методах data и headerData для роли Qt::BackgroundRole выбрать цвет. Ну как то так. Вроде бы в примерах есть. Только не для QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: а ещё лучше сделать Proxy-модель: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2-qtableview-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94/846522#846522